# Take a PNG image/bufferedimage and add it to an already existing PDF

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I am trying create a class that takes an image, it can be a bufferedimage, renderedimage or an image file of type png, gif or jpeg and add that to an already existing PDF.

I have tried using both a buffered image and rendered image and passing it to the function and adding that to the PDF but always got errors so I am trying now to add a image file to a PDF and I keep getting different errors at runtime when I change any of the code.

The current error I am getting is:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException

The code I am currently trying to use is:

```
public ExportToPDF() throws IOException {



    PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter("pdf.pdf"));


    java.awt.Image image1 = ImageIO.read(new File("test.gif"));



    Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc);


    pdfDoc.addNewPage(PageSize.A4);

    doc.add(image1);


    doc.close();

}
```

I have spent hours on this so far and seriously can't find a way of getting it to work, any help would be greatly appreciated. I have scoured the internet looking for help and the only ways I have seen that I haven't tried are using .getInstance however when I attempt to use that it says cannot resolve symbol.

Any help would seriously be massively appreciated.

Full stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
at java.io.RandomAccessFile.readBytes(Native Method)
at java.io.RandomAccessFile.read(RandomAccessFile.java:377)
at javax.imageio.stream.FileImageInputStream.read(FileImageInputStream.java:117)
at com.sun.imageio.plugins.common.SubImageInputStream.read(SubImageInputStream.java:61)
at com.sun.imageio.plugins.common.InputStreamAdapter.read(InputStreamAdapter.java:47)
at java.io.SequenceInputStream.read(SequenceInputStream.java:207)
at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.fill(InflaterInputStream.java:238)
at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:158)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:265)
at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:83)
at com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageReader.decodePass(PNGImageReader.java:1112)
at com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageReader.decodeImage(PNGImageReader.java:1223)
at com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageReader.readImage(PNGImageReader.java:1338)
at com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageReader.read(PNGImageReader.java:1614)
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1448)
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1308)
at CE201.ExportToPDF.<init>(ExportToPDF.java:26)
at CE201.CsvGUI$7.actionPerformed(CsvGUI.java:256)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

The code I am using to generate the PNG file is as follows:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    WritableImage img = fxPanel.getScene().snapshot(null);
                    File file = new File("test.png");
                    RenderedImage renderedImage = SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(img, null);

                    try {
                        ImageIO.write(renderedImage, "PNG", file);
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Try moving `pdfDoc.addNewPage(PageSize.A4);` to **before** `Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc);`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Thank you for advice, I tried that and still get the same error.

Comment: You didn't post a full stack trace, exactly which line throws the `IndexOutOfBoundsException`?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I've added it, thank you

Comment: You don't have a file "test.gif". Add the full path to your gif (and make sure it is a valid image file). Actually, why does your png file end in gif? Maybe double check that too.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I should have said, I changed the file to be a png file since the gif file which I created earlier in the program had colour errors. I do have the png file in the correct directory.

Comment: It isn't a valid png file (at least the Java libraries can't read it).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I have added the code I use to generate the PNG file. Is there anything you can see that is incorrect since once it is generated I can open the file without an error?

Comment: test.png != test.gif Also you need to wait for IO to finish if you're going to use files.

Comment: How can I wait for IO to finish?